# Determine whether a list item is a parent or child task in a sharepoint task list and modify its appearance in a powerapp gallery as a result

Tags: sharepoint, ms-project, powerapps

I'm using PowerApps to build a project management reporting interface, and I'd like to indicate on the main list of tasks whether something is a main task with subtasks or a subtask. We are syncing a microsoft project file with a sharepoint task list, and the mobile interface provided by sharepoint is bad. I can't find a task item property that is accessible within a powerapps query that will indicate this

I've iterated through all of the task item properties that are apparently exposed to the list connector, and none of them seem to indicate when something is a subtask. isFolder always returns false, even on top level tasks, so it seems like that property isn't being used to track this.

I expect to be able to build a conditional so that when my gallery is populated I can indicate if something has subordinate subtasks, how many there are, and allow people to browse to them. No matter what I've tried so far the list appears to populate unsorted and without any distinction between master tasks and subtasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a similar problem; the current connector to Project Online is very rudimentary. However, if you have access to Power BI you can use the ProjectData REST api to send an OData query to get everything you are looking for. Power BI is much better for reporting/browsing data, and if you need to edit the SharePoint list you can embed PowerApps within a Power BI report.

Have also looked at using PowerApps to edit MS Project tasks, but as you noticed the connector is not fully functional. I think this may be by design; even the REST APIs do not allow for setting baselines, you have to open the file in MS Project Pro to have full access.